# What is a latin stem for swap?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, new-latin

I don't know if I asked this question correctly, but what is a latin stem for swap? I don't specifically need it to be just swap. You can answer my question by saying a latin stm for switch, or another adj. for swap. Please, any of you, please get back to me as soon as you can. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you give an example sentence or otherwise describe the context? It can make a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious verb to use seems to me to be [*permutare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=permuto&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060), which can very literally mean to transform completely or to turn about, but also to exchange or swap. Its attendant noun is [*permutatio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=permutatio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).

Depending on what you mean exactly I could envision constructions with [*transponere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtranspono) or some of the various verbs associated with commerce, like [*cambire*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=cambio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) (which is not Classical Latin but gave rise to English *change*).